# Lightening component recordUpdated method binding triggers stale data event

Tags: salesforce, updates, lwc

I've a lightening component which will call a controller method on update action. Below is the code of the component, controller and helper:
Component code:

```
    <force:recordData aura:id="forceRecord"
        recordId="{!v.recordId}" 
        layoutType="FULL"
        targetRecord="{!v._record}"
        targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
        targetError="{!v._error}"
        mode="EDIT"
        recordUpdated="{!c.recordUpdated}" />
```

Controller code:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.checkStatus(component,event,helper);        
    },

    recordUpdated : function(component, event, helper) {
        var changeType = event.getParams().changeType;

        console.log('changeType IS: '+ changeType);

        // changeType = LOADED  -- when record is created.
        if (changeType === "ERROR") { /* handle error; do this first! */ }
        else if (changeType === "LOADED") {
        }
        else if (changeType === "REMOVED") { /* handle record removal */ }
        else if (changeType === "CHANGED") {
            var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
            console.log('Updated record Id: '+ recordId);
            helper.callAnotherMethod(component, event, helper);  
         }
    }
})
```

Assume that I'm accessing payment (Id in URL: a001l000005JP5mAAG) page in the browser and modified some field in it and saved it. recordUpdated method is called and it enters CHANGED if condition.

I open some other payment (Id in URL: a001l000005HK5mBBK) in the same browser window and modify a field value in this payment and save it. At this moment recordUpdated method is called twice once for the old payment and once for the new payment.

If I look at the browser console I see the log as below:

```
changeType IS: CHANGED
Updated record Id: a001l000005JP5mAAG
changeType IS: CHANGED
Updated record Id: a001l000005HK5mBBK
```

Not sure why it is calling twice and how to stop it? Can anybody explain me why it acting like that and how to stop it?

Surprisingly if I open more payments in the same browser window and modify them it keeps adding recordUpdated event for the current payment updated and also calls update event of earlier payments with their Id.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of research and deliberation, I understood that this is an issue with event listeners being added but not removed if multiple same object types are viewed and events generated in the same browser window.

I found that even though multiple events raised but if I check the changed fields in those events they will not have any data except the one changed in the current instance, hence I started checking changed fields as shown below and if they don't have any elements in the changed object then I'm moving on.

```
    recordUpdated : function(component, event, helper) {
        var changeType = event.getParams().changeType;
        var changedFields = event.getParams().changedFields;

        console.log('changeType IS: '+ changeType);

        // changeType = LOADED  -- when record is created.
        if (changeType === "ERROR") { /* handle error; do this first! */ }
        else if (changeType === "LOADED") {
        }
        else if (changeType === "REMOVED") { /* handle record removal */ }
        else if (changeType === "CHANGED") {
            if (Object.keys(changedFields).length == 1 
                && Object.keys(Object.values(changedFields)[0])[0] == 'SystemModstamp')
            { 
                // this is a case where nothing modified but due to issue in lightning event handlers all the 
                // previous events are fired along with the current event, hence avoiding action on such events.
            }
            else
            {
                var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
                console.log('To be updated record Id: '+ recordId);
                console.log('changedFields: '+ JSON.stringify(changedFields));

                helper.callAnyMethod(component, event, helper);
            }
        }

    },
    destoryCmp : function (component, event, helper) {
        component.destroy();
    },
})
```

This solved issue for me. Hope this might help if anyone else faces similar issue.